# write a jQuery code, where I have to clone a div on button click. New div should have fresh new dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, jquery-clone

JQUERY:

```
 $("#panel_moreInfoDetails_common3").clone().appendTo("#panel_moreInfoDetails_common2");
```

I am able to clone the div, but I need dropdown list in it. Notice that my dropdown options are in foreach loop. HTML is given below
HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="panel_moreInfoDetails_common3">
     <div class="delete-moreinfodetails" style="margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 20px;margin-right: 18px;">
         <a data-id="@record.UserFieldIndexNumber" id="button-delete-moreinfodetails" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class='icon icon-bin3'></i>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div id="@string.Format("field_{0}_{1}", Model.Page, record.UserFieldIndexNumber)" class="col settings-field @(fields.Contains(string.Format("field_{0}_{1}", Model.Page, record.UserFieldIndexNumber)) ? "hidden" : "")">
        <select class="moreinfo-details" id="@string.Format("field_{0}_{1}", Model.Page, record.UserFieldIndexNumber)" name="@string.Format("field_{0}_{1}", Model.Page, record.UserFieldIndexNumber)" data-field="Info Details">
             <option value="">Select an option</option>
             @foreach (var item in Model.MoreInfoDetailsValues)
             {
                   //selected = record.UserDefinedDropDownField == item.UserDefinedDropDownField ? "selected='selected'" : "";
                   <option data-desc="@item.UserDefinedDropDownField" @selected value="@item.UserDefinedDropDownField">@item.UserDefinedDropDownField</option>
             }
        </select>
     </div>
     <div id="@string.Format("field_{0}_{1}", Model.Page, record.UserFieldIndexNumber)" class="col settings-field @(fields.Contains(string.Format("field_{0}_{1}", Model.Page, record.UserFieldIndexNumber)) ? "hidden" : "")">

          <input data-ufindex="@record.UserFieldIndexNumber" type="text" class="form-control" value="@record.UserFieldValue" />

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having specifically? It clones but what?

Comment: I am able to clone a div, but under that div I have a dropdown. I want to clone that too with all options in dropdown I have right now.

Comment: I got what you are saying and I tried doing that
.clone(true, true). But now when I get a new dropdown and I click on it to select any option, instead of new dropdown the previous one is getting clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3hjfj/)

> [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents)
>
> `.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )`
>
> deepWithDataAndEvents (default: value of withDataAndEvents)
>
> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. By default its value matches the first argument's value (which defaults to false).

What you are looking for is `.clone(true, true)`

`$("#panel_moreInfoDetails_common3").clone(true, true).appendTo("#panel_moreInfoDetails_common2");`

Comment: $("#panel_moreInfoDetails_common3").clone(true, true).appendTo("#panel_moreInfoDetails_common2");
This approach worked for me, maybe I am missing something with html part or the selectors to reach there. 
 I tried doing this .clone(true, true). But now when I get a new dropdown and I click on it to select any option, instead of new dropdown the previous one is getting clicked or the one from where  I cloned it.

Comment: You need to modify id, name and possibly class attributes in the clone. You are getting duplicate ids this way, which is never a good thing.